# Server's NonBlocking TCP socket taking time to stream content

Tags: c++, sockets, select, send, nonblocking

**Problem**
- I am working on a Streaming server & created a nonblocking socket using:

```
flag=fcntl(m_fd,F_GETFL);
flag|=O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(m_fd,F_SETFL,flag);
```

Server then sends the Media file contents using code:

```
bool SendData(const char *pData,long nSize)
{
    int fd=m_pSock->get_fd();
    fd_set write_flag;
    while(1)
    {   
        FD_ZERO(&write_flag);
        FD_SET(fd,&write_flag);
        struct timeval tout;
        tout.tv_sec=0;
        tout.tv_usec=500000;

        int res=select(fd+1,0,&write_flag,0,&tout);
        if(-1==res)
        {
            print("select() failure\n");
            return false;
        }
        if(1==res)
        {
            unsigned long sndLen=0;
            if(!m_pSock->send(pData,nSize,&sndLen))
            {
                print(socket send() failure\n");
                return false;
            }
            nSize-=sndLen;
            if(!nSize)
            return true;    //everything is sent
        }
    }
}
```

Using above code, I am streaming a say *200sec* audio file, which I expect that Server should stream it in *2-3secs* using full n/w available bandwidth(Throttle off), but the problem is that Server is taking *199~200secs* to stream full contents.
While debugging, I commented the

> m_pSock->send()

section & tried to dump the file locally. It takes *1~2secs* to dump the file.

**Questions**
- If I am using a NonBlocking TCP socket, why does *send()* taking so much time?

- Since the data is always available, *select()* will return immediately *(as we have seen while dumping the file*). Does that mean *send()* is affected by the *recv()* on the client side?

Any inputs on this would be helpul. Client behavior is not in our scope.

Comment: TCP socket size is 64KB, but I am sending 32KB. I tried increasing this to 1MB & get 25-30% improvement, but still Server is not streaming as it should do in Throttle off mode(i.e. 2~3 secs max for a 15 MB file suppose). Just tested, when client requests Server, it takes 0-2 msec to start streaming.

Comment: What is "Throttle off" supposed to mean ? What does your code do when you hit the timeout in select() ? How do you know the client end receives data as fast as it can, and is not employing flow control to limit the bandwidth ?

Comment: Throttle off in Streaming means that Server would sends the contents getting max available bandwidth. If Throttle is on, Server would send contents based on Frame TimeStamp values(i.e send Frame just before it has to be displayed). In Throttle On case, Server should stream contents in "file duration" time. I have written a sepearte code for Throttle on case which is working fine.   For the above code, I am assuming that timeout will never happen, as we are already having the data in the function.

Comment: You mean, If client is not reading that fast, atleast it should have a enough buffer to store all contents.

Comment: Why should it have such a big buffer ? How are you sure of that ? And how big is the file you're sending ?

Comment: I need a info on this... Suppose I am using a Streaming Server like Youtube which is streaming contents to its various clients/Devices. I hope on client request, the Youtube Server will stream contents immidealtely from its side irrespective of the client side handling..Is my above statment right or wrong??

Comment: @user1409528: It depends on how the flash player on the client is configured. If it is configured to buffer everything, then the client will read as fast as it can. But the bottom line is that the server cannot send the file faster than the client is reading it.

Comment: @user1409528 It depends on the client, not the server. Some clients (e.g. the youtube flash player) will buffer received data to the harddrive. Some other client might not do that.

Comment: @user315052: If client is configured to buffered everything, then why can't the server send the file faster. Reading the file is a seperate activity by client.

Comment: Yes, that's what @nos and I are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is probably doing some buffering to avoid network jitter, but it is likely still playing the audio file in real time. So, the file transfer rate is matched to the rate that the client is consuming the data. Since it is a 200 second audio file, it will take about 200 seconds to complete the transfer.

Comment: Does increasing the OS buffer would help?

Comment: @user1409528 That would mean you could push your data into kernel buffers faster, it would not increase the transmission speed on the network.

Comment: @user1409528: How much improvement you see depends on the TCP configuration of client and server. If they are configured to scale up their window sizes and if somehow the TCP window size scaled up to handle 1 minute of audio, that would explain your 25%-30% increase in speed.

Answer (score 0):

Because TCP output and input buffers are propably much smaller than the audio file, reading speed of the receiving application can slow down the sending speed.

When both the TCP output buffer of sender and the input buffer of receiver are both full, TCP stack of the sender is not able to receive any data from the sender. So sending will be blocked, until there is space.

If the receiver reads the TCP stream same speed as data is needed for playing. Then the transfer takes about 200 seconds. Or little bit less.

This can be avoided by using application layer buffering in the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that if the client side is using blocking TCP, plus is processing all the data on a single thread with no no buffer/queue etc right through to the "player" of the file, then your side being non-blocking will only speed things until you reach the point where the TCP/IP protocol stack buffers, NIC buffers etc are full. Then you will ultimately still only be able to send data as fast as the client side is consuming it. Remember TCP is a reliable, point-to-point protocol.

Where does your client code come from in your testing? Is it some sort of simple test client someone has written?